# refer to an intent from within onClick(View v) method

Tags: android

```
public void onClick(View v) {
      switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
          break;
        case R.id.button2:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ThirdActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
          break;
      }
  }
```

instead of the above approach is it possible to create an instance of Intent outside the onClick(View v) method and refer to it from within onClick(View v) method?

Comment: have you tried it?? I think it is perfectly ok to do that

Comment: yes. it's possible.. but why to give memeory for Intents by declaring and intializing as global instances?

Comment: is there any security issue with doing so? in the global context...

Comment: thanks vipul, Gopal yeah where memory is concerned, should avoid it.

Comment: Yes, its is possible. you can do it by declaring your intent variable as a class member for activity.and no security issue. but it is not advisable to have an intent variable declared as a member.

Comment: Why do you need it? I mean, an intent is like any other variable. You should create, use and destroy. Globals are bad design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean doing something like this :-

```
Intent intent1;
public void onClick(View v) {

      switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
          break;
        case R.id.button2:
            intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ThirdActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
          break;
      }
  }
```

This will make the intent1 **global** and will have a lifetime of an entire class not just a function. A global variable will be garbage collected once the activity is finished, on the other a local variable has a very short lifetime and only lives until the function doesn't exits.

Use of global variables is encouraged where that particular variable is needed for the entire lifetime of that activity, else it will be wasting memory.

Comment: thanks for pointing out global intents can be used throughout the life time of the activity.

Comment: You are welcome, if this answer solved your query then mark this question solved.